# What does it mean for a sorting algorithm to be "stable"?

Tags: sorting

In reading about various sorting algorithms I've seen it mentioned that some are "stable" and some are not. What does that mean, and what tradeoffs are involved on that basis when selecting an algorithm?

Comment: This question would be easily answered within a minute with wikipedia. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm

Comment: @MareInfinitus More precisely : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability

Comment: here is a good answer [https://class.coursera.org/algs4partI-005/lecture/34](https://class.coursera.org/algs4partI-005/lecture/34)

Comment: This is a question lacking own research. Answered with a wikipedia picture. And it gets really good feedback, which somehow makes me sad. IMHO it should be closed, and not get upvotes.

Comment: On the other hand, I just saw this and learned something new. If I had known that I didn't know this then I could have researched it but because the OP asked the question I now know what I didn't know that I didn't know.

Comment: Most of the time one does not know, what one does not know (sic). Anybody (involved in software-development) who cannot be waked up at 3AM and answer what stable means in the context of sorting has to fix some basic knowledge problems.

Comment: Generally, "just google it" or "look it up on wikipedia" are not considerable acceptable responses on StackExchange sites. Because they do not provide an answer to what the complainer is verifying as a valid question with the call to the authorities of google and wikipedia. IF the question is easily a duplicate of another question or questions within programmers.stackexchange, then you can complain.

Comment: I think the level of response this question has gotten more than validates that it's appropriate to ask here. Most of stack exchange could be replaced with wikipedia, but that's not the intent of the site.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517793/stability-in-sorting-algorithms

Answer (score 94, accepted):

A stable sort is one which preserves the original order of the input set, *where the comparison algorithm does not distinguish between two or more items.*

Consider a sorting algorithm that sorts cards by *rank*, but not by suit.  The stable sort will guarantee that the original order of cards having the same rank is preserved; the unstable sort will not.

[image]

Comment: Correction: The unstable algorithm exhibits undefined behaviour when two elements are equal, it is perfectly possible that the order is sometimes preserved.

Comment: Nice picture, very similar to wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm

Comment: @MareInfinitus: It's in the public domain.  Check the attribution on the original image.

Comment: A good picture explains faster and deeper than a lot of words on the average case. Legal issues were not what I wanted to talk about.

Comment: To the suggested editor who keeps trying to change the word in the last sentence from **suit** to **rank**, *you're getting it wrong.*  The sentence is correct in its current form.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Actually, I believe the editor is correct. Your post currently says that a stable sort preserves the ordering of cards in the same suit, but cards in the same suit will have different ranks and thus must be rearranged to achieve sorted order. For example the sort does not preserve the order of the 2 and the 5 of hearts. It's the ordering of cards with the same _rank_ (and different suits) that makes the difference between stable and unstable.

Answer (score 26):

Stable algorithms preserve the relative order of elements.

So a stable sorting algorithm will retain the relative order of values which compare as equal.

Consider a sorting algorithm where we sort a collection of 2d points based on their X dimension.

Collection to be sorted: `{(6, 3), (5, 5), (6, 1), (1, 3)}`

Stable Sorted: `{(1, 3), (5, 5), (6, 3), (6, 1)}`

Regular Sorted: Either `{(1, 3), (5, 5), (6, 3), (6, 1)}`, or `{(1, 3), (5, 5), (6, 1), (6, 3)}`

---

As for the tradeoff... well, stable sorting is less efficient, but sometimes you need it.

For example when a user clicks the a column header to sort values in a UI, it's reasonable to expect his previous sorting order to be used in the case of equal values.

Comment: Is it less efficient though? It seems "obvious", but some of the best sorting algorithms are stable by nature (e.g. anything based on merge sort, such as Tim sort), they don't need to do any explicit extra work to be stable.

Comment: Stable has nothing to do with performance in general. Mergesort runs in O(n*log n) and is stable. Heapsort has similar performance, but is not stable.

Comment: "Stable" can also apply to data-structures, eg. a "stable heap" is a heap which dequeues items that have the same priority in the same order they were queued.  This is very important for efficient path-finding algorithms.

Comment: There are no stable sorts which are *O(n ln n)* comparisons and also *O(1)* on memory.  Speed is not the only measure of efficiency.  The fact that you can't stable sort in-place matters.

Comment: @QuestionC It appears [block sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_sort) is stable and fits those bounds.

Comment: @delnan First paper in 69 but pretty much unknown (don't remember seeing it in either Knuth nor CLRS), did you run into that one in some practical application? Interesting.

Comment: @QuestionC Actually I ran into it going through Wikipedia's table of sorting functions. I didn't see it anywhere else either, it seems to be somewhat obscure. I suspect that's because the "stable and in-place" requirement is rare to begin with and most people facing such a situation just swallow the additional comparisons of other, simpler alternatives. Mergesort can be made in-place at an extra log n factor, i.e. O(n * log n * log n) comparisons total. Block sort seems quite complex and who knows how well it works on real data.

Comment: @QuestionC But here's another algorithm that I've actually seen around: [WikiSort](https://github.com/BonzaiThePenguin/WikiSort/tree/master). Don't know anyone using it in production though.

Comment: In regard to use case, if my original list is unsorted, what a real world application where I'd want to keep this arbitrary preservation of "rank"?  Like if the deck of cards is random, why is the heart preferential to the spade?  What is a situation when this might matter?